# how to set a Future date Time stamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am Learning MySQL DB & am currently on Date & Time Stamp, I've tried searching for this problem on the net but it seems there is no proper answer.....

Now in my DB there is 1 column that needs to record a date value when the record is added.

Now as per conventional Wisdom the first thing that comes to mind is the Date & Time Stamp method, so i declare it when adding this column to the DB.

**Code**

```
    mysql> ALTER TABLE 
           ISSUEBOOKS 
           ADD COLUMN 
           RETURNDATE timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The problem is i need this date to be a date of the future, namely; a fixed 10 days.
Like I said I've tried searching for a solution to this problem but couldn't find any, so any help here would be great ...!!

Comment: You can't do that with `DEFAULT`. You'll need to do it explicitly in the code that inserts the row.

Comment: You can also do it in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: `SET NEW.returndate = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`